# Proper way to exit a WxWidgets application

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

I am looking for the proper way to exit a WxWidgets application.
Right now to exit I call **wxGetApp().ExitMainLoop()** when my main wxFrame is closed. Then I expect my application **OnExit** method to be called so I can properly terminate the application.
In term of code it looks like:

```
void MainFrame::onClose(wxCloseEvent& ev)
{
    wxGetApp().ExitMainLoop();
}

//...  

int MyApp::OnExit()
{
    wxBusyCursor wait;
    /* Free all non-wxWidgets memory here*/

    return 0;
}
```

MainFrame::onClose is successfully called when the user request to close the application.
But **MyApp::OnExit is sometimes called, sometimes not.**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you don't need to call `ExitMainLoop()` at all when the last frame is closed because by default closing it does exactly this anyhow.

But whether you do it or not, `OnExit()` should still definitely be called, so if it isn't, it's due to something else not shown here. As usual, the best way to debug such mysterious problems is to start from something working, e.g. the minimal sample from `samples/minimal` subdirectory of wxWidgets source distribution, and try reproducing the problem in it by progressively modifying it to do what your real program does.